# use foreach with switch function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have i my database a table who returns the sections from the site the problem is not returning the first registry in the database here is the code:

```
$mysqli = $conexion_temporal; //connect to mysqli
$queryn = $mysqli->query('select * from sections'); //we get the content
$dataset = array(); //we declare an array
while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array()) {    
   $dataset['seo'] = $data['seo'];
 }



switch ($pagina) {  //switch the sections
    case 'compra_completa':
        echo $plantilla->SuccessPurchase();
        break;
    case $dataset['seo']: //the seo column of the database
        echo $plantilla->album($dataset['seo'],$subcat);
        $subcat = $_GET['subcat']; //if we request category we show ..
        break;
    }
```

the problem is not getting the first column of the database
http://prntscr.com/60gjzd

edit: only works the last inserted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$dataset['seo'] will always be overwrote by $data['seo'], that's why u only get the last inserted data

```
$dataset['seo'] = $data['seo'];
```

If you need to store all data to dataset you should be use array_push

```
while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array()) {    
    array_push($dataset,$data['seo']);
}
```

From my understanding, Is these what you wants?

```
$mysqli = $conexion_temporal; //connect to mysqli
$queryn = $mysqli->query('select * from sections'); //we get the content
$dataset = array(); //we declare an array

//find section
$matched_section = false;

while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array()) {
    array_push($dataset,$data['seo']);

    //if section match store as $matched_section
    if($data['seo'] == $pagina)
        $matched_section = $data['seo'];
}

if($pagina == 'compra_completa'){
    echo $plantilla->SuccessPurchase();
}else if( matched_section ){
    echo $plantilla->album(matched_section,$subcat);
    $subcat = $_GET['subcat']; //if we request category we show ..
}else{
    ........
}
```

Comment: Is these what you wants?

Answer (score 1):

Try by using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant to the fetch_array() function as below when there is single row:

```
while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    
   $dataset[] = $data['seo'];
 }
```

For switch cases on multiple sections use foreach:

```
foreach ($dataset as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        case $value : 
            // do something
            break ;

     }
 }
```

Comment: and how i use with the switch statement?

Comment: help? please? its confusing

Comment: I am not getting what you are doing as there may be multiple sections then which section you want to use in switch case as all can't be used.

Comment: i only want to show in case x: each section stored  with the function album

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    
   $dataset['seo'] = $data['seo'];
 }
```

this keeps rewriting $dataset['seo'] with every value it reads until it ends at the last one.

either you can use array_push as was suggested before, and then make another loop for your switch to read it again, or you can put it all in the first loop like this:

```
    while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array()) {    
    switch ($pagina) {  //switch the sections
        case 'compra_completa':
            echo $plantilla->SuccessPurchase();
            break;
        case $data['seo']: //the seo column of the database
            echo $plantilla->album($data['seo'],$subcat);
            $subcat = $_GET['subcat']; //if we request category we show ..
            break;
        }
}
```

this will execute your switch block for every row on column seo, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: i can only go as far as you've told me, i don't know what your DB looks like, what's $pagina, or what are you trying to accomplish. i can only tell you that this will make your switch statement execute on every row, but i can't tell you whether your switch statement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find your code with some edits in order to make it work.

```
$mysqli = $conexion_temporal; //connect to mysqli
$queryn = $mysqli->query('select * from sections'); //we get the content
$dataset = array(); //we declare an array

// I made a fix here because the $data['seo'] was not
// added to the array correctly.
// I also added the MYSQLI_ASSOC parameter
while ($data = $queryn->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    
   $dataset[] = $data['seo'];
}

// I added a foreach to loop through all your 'paginas'
foreach ($dataset as $pagina) {
    switch ($pagina) {  //switch the sections
        case 'compra_completa':
            echo $plantilla->SuccessPurchase();
            break;
        case $dataset['seo']: //the seo column of the database
            echo $plantilla->album($dataset['seo'],$subcat);
            $subcat = $_GET['subcat']; //if we request category we show ..
            break;
    }
}
```